# How do I know the checkbox checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have this Jqgrid with the function multiselect = true. Now, I would like know how do I know if the checkbox is checked? I need to know, because if the checkbox is checked, I send message to this people. I think I need of FOR, but i don't know how do I use it

```
$.getJSON("/Page/pop", function (data) {
            var data = data;

            $('#table').jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: data,
                colNames: ['Code', 'Client', 'Email', 'Copy Email', ''],
                colModel: [

                            { name: 'rec', index: 'rec' },
                            { name: 'nmcli', index: 'nmcli' },
                            { name: 'listEm', index: 'listEm' },
                            { name: 'listEmCp', index: 'listEmCp' },
                            { name: 'cdrec', index: 'cdrec', hidden: true}],
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true,
                imgpath: 'jqGrid-3.4.3/themes/coffee/images',
                height: 'auto',
                width: 1680
            });
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

Comment: unfortunately i dont see any checkbox here but an ajax request

Comment: use this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/Y9KgQ/)..

Comment: multiselect: true = checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid supports callbacks `onSelectRow`, `onSelectAll` and events `jqGridSelectRow` and `jqGridSelectAll` "to inform" your that the user selects some row of the grid. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents).

I would recommend you additionally to remove `imgpath` option which is not exists in jqGrid since many years (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)), add `gridview: true` option to improve performance of the grid, add `autoencode: true` to be sure that any data (inclusive special HTML charachters) will be successfuly displayed in the grid and remove all `index` properties from `colModel`.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. When I checked 1 checkbox, it works correctly, but if I checked 2 or more, it doesn't works correctly

Comment: @Developer123: You are welcome! What you mean under "works correctly"? What code you use in your attempts? `onSelectRow` for example sill be called if the user check or uncheck one row. The second parameter of the callback shows the state of the row. If you need to get ids of *all* currently checked rows you can use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow")`.

Answer (score 0):

if ($('#ckBox').is(':checked')) {

/* do something */

}

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Jqgrid is, but anyway

$("checkbox-selector").is(":checked")

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     alert( $(this).val() );
  }
});
```

[Demo of link](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/Y9KgQ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkids() 
 {
        var s;
        s = jQuery('#EmailTable').getGridParam('selarrrow');
        if (s == "") 
        {
            alert("No record selected.");
            return false;
        }
  }
 Call checkids() function on button click event.
```